# Recently SQL Server crashed with error code 0x3d88

Tags: exception, application-error, sql-server-2019-express

I have got some problem with SQL Server 2019 Express. It has stopped working once or twice a week.

I executed `checkdb` command on my database but it didn't return any errors.

```
Commands completed successfully. Completion time: 2023-02-22T13:21:19.2491168+01:00
```

I checked Windows event viewer near time of shutdown SQL Server.

Here is what I found:

```
Nazwa dziennika:Application
Źródło:        Application Error
Data:          22.02.2023 12:51:24
Identyfikator zdarzenia:1000
Kategoria zadania:(100)
Poziom:        Błędy
Słowa kluczowe:Klasyczny
Użytkownik:    Nie dotyczy
Komputer:      SERWER2022
Opis:
Nazwa aplikacji powodującej błąd: sqlservr.exe, wersja: 2019.150.2101.7, sygnatura czasowa: 0x63cf0e6d
Nazwa modułu powodującego błąd: sqlTsEs.dll, wersja: 2019.150.2101.7, sygnatura czasowa: 0x63cf0e74
Kod wyjątku: 0xc0000005
Przesunięcie błędu: 0x00000000000029b1
Identyfikator procesu powodującego błąd: 0x3d88
Godzina uruchomienia aplikacji powodującej błąd: 0x01d945fd3478261e
Ścieżka aplikacji powodującej błąd: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe
Ścieżka modułu powodującego błąd: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn\sqlTsEs.dll
Identyfikator raportu: d1fb554a-2ccb-44c2-9bbb-230ac30e73d5
Pełna nazwa pakietu powodującego błąd: 
Identyfikator aplikacji względem pakietu powodującego błąd: 
Kod XML zdarzenia:

  
    
    1000
    0
    2
    100
    0
    0x80000000000000
    
    177818
    
    
    Application
    SERWER2022
    
  
  
    sqlservr.exe
    2019.150.2101.7
    63cf0e6d
    sqlTsEs.dll
    2019.150.2101.7
    63cf0e74
    c0000005
    00000000000029b1
    3d88
    01d945fd3478261e
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn\sqlTsEs.dll
    d1fb554a-2ccb-44c2-9bbb-230ac30e73d5
```

After I manually start up SQL Server, it works well but until some time...

Recently it happens on Thursday around 2 PM o'clock. Please help me resolve that problem.

I checked database looking for errors using 'checkdb' and this didn't return any errors / problems.

I spent long time to find what is wrong with SQL Server / Windows settings but did not find anything.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/283500/sql-server-2019-service-terminated-unexpectedly-at-startup-but-manually-starts. ?